# Winston for nestsjs return duplicates messages for file transport

Tags: logging, nestjs, winston

I'm trying to configure multiple wibston logger for my application to log in different files but I'm facing to the problem that sometimes I receive duplicates messages.

I'm using the following code to initialize the logger

```
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import { format, transports } from 'winston';
import 'winston-daily-rotate-file';

const wistonConfig = (filename: string) =\> ({
format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
transports: \[
new transports.Console(),
new transports.DailyRotateFile({
filename,
datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
maxFiles: process.env.KEEP_LOG_DAYS || 30,
zippedArchive: true,
}),
\],
});

export const createCustomLogger = (filename: string) =\>
WinstonModule.createLogger(wistonConfig(`logs/${filename}-%DATE%.log`));
```

And then calling it like:
`let logger = createLogger('mqtt-input');  logger.log('hello')`

I get the following output in the file:
`{"level":"info","message":"hello","timestamp":"2023-09-26T14:57:58.802Z"} {"level":"info","message":"hello","timestamp":"2023-09-26T14:57:58.819Z"}`

But in the console I've go the correct output:

`{"level":"info","message":"hello","timestamp":"2023-09-26T14:57:58.819Z"}`

I've tried to debug the application by setting a break point before the logger.log call, but when the debugger stops the first message has been written to the file and when I step forward the debugger the second message is sent.

I've also tried to use different transport from DailyRotateFile (like File) but also failing.